# How do I get my data to show me the number of rows using NodeJS and Express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am brand new to Node and Express and I'm not sure if I am setting this up correctly. My goal is to create a subdomain where I can take data I have further down in the code and export the number of rows in that dataset.
This is the code I am using currently, but when I refresh, the server times out.

```
var app = express();

app.use('/db_benchmark', function(req, res){
    (req.data_being_requested, function(rows) {
        res.send('Hello World got ' + rows.length);
    });
});
```

Do I need to put this after the data has been called? If so, what would I use? Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you need the second callback function

```
var app = express();

app.use('/db_benchmark', function(req, res){
    var rows = req.data_being_requested;
    res.send('Hello World got ' + rows.length);
});
```

Just store the request data and send the length info in the response